# Changing header format for non-numbered chapters with \chapter*{}

Tags: header-footer, templates

I  set up header and footer styles, and I receive output like in the picture given. All chapter header formats are as I want, except the chapters defined by \chapter*{} command. Because this command does not assign a number for the chapter.

I want to have my header "Introduction" instead of "Chapter 0. Introduction" (shown in pic.). I write 'if' condition code 
`\ifnum\value{chapter}<1 \renewcommand{\chaptermarkformat}{} \fi` line in my code block in .cls file. 
However, it doesn't work as i want.[image]

```
\RequirePackage[markcase=used]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\providepairofpagestyles{thesisSimple}{%
\clearpairofpagestyles%
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\ohead{%
    \headmark
    \ifnum\value{chapter}<1 \renewcommand{\chaptermarkformat}{} \fi
}
\ihead{}% Outer header
\ifoot{}% Inner footer
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}% Outer footer
}
\pagestyle{thesisSimple}
\providepairofpagestyles[thesisSimple]{thesis}{\automark*[section]{}}
\providepairofpagestyles[thesisSimple]{review}{%
    \ofoot[\ttitle/\authorname]{\ttitle/\authorname}
    \ifoot[\today]{\today}
}
```

Anyone can help to to remove 'Chapter 0.' for the chapters defined by \chapter*{}. This problem is same for appendices.

Comment: Are you using \addchap{introduction}? No. Do it!

Comment: Leave the class untouched. Modified classes are not supported. Have a look the license too.

Comment: Thanks, it works better. But what is the difference of using "\chapter*{}" and "\addchap{}" .

Comment: The difference is: adchap does what you want. A starred chapter doesn't.

Comment: If you want to know all the differences have a look into section 3.16 of the [KOMA-Script manual](http://www.komascript.de/scrguide).

Comment: I have to say though, that not all features of Koma are supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redefinitions in clas files are never a great idea. It makes support far more complex (that modified class won't get good support) and there are license issue you have to oversee.

If you leave the class untouched, it is very simple to not have the problem. An Introduction in bigger projects is printed within the frontmatter, where chapters are unnumbered (Wombat below). If you want an unnumbered chapter in the mainmatter, use `\addchap`. It will get the correct header and also add an entry to the table of contents.

```
\documentclass[english]{MastersDoctoralThesis} % The class file specifying the document structure
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter % Use roman page numbering style (i, ii, iii, iv...) for the pre-content pages
\tableofcontents % Prints the main table of contents
\chapter{Wombat}
\blindtext[10]
\mainmatter % Begin numeric (1,2,3...) page numbering
\pagestyle{thesis} % Return the page headers back to the "thesis" style
\addchap{Capybara}
\blindtext[10]
\appendix
\addchap{Duck}
\blindtext[10]
\addsec{Duckling}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

A few words about this can be found in the [unofficial quick manual](https://github.com/johannesbottcher/MDT-Quick-Manual/).